What's the new memalignment function useful for?
In Annex M of this draft, I found:

added memalignment function to query the alignment of a pointer;

and then its documentation:

7.24.9 Alignment of memory
7.24.9.1 The memalignment function
Synopsis
#include <stdlib.h> size_t memalignment(const void *p);
Description
The memalignment function accepts a pointer to any object and returns the maximum
alignment satisfied by its address value. The alignment may be an
extended alignment and may also be beyond the range supported by the
implementation for explicit use by alignas. 359) If so, it will
satisfy all alignments usable by the implementation. The value
returned can be compared to the result of alignof, and if it is
greater or equal, the alignment requirement for the type operand is
satisfied.
Returns
The alignment of the pointer p, which is a power of two. If p is a null pointer, an alignment of zero is returned.
NOTE
An alignment of zero indicates that the tested pointer cannot be
used to access an object of any type.

Question: What do "maximum alignment" and "extended alignment" mean in layman's terms, and can't the alignment of a pointer be found with the alignof operator?

Section 6.2.8 ¶3 specifies 'extended alignment'.  The alignof(…) operator takes a type name where I used … — a pointer is not a type name so you can't find the alignment of a pointer with alignof.


Question: What do "maximum alignment" and "extended alignment" mean in layman's terms,…

An address is aligned modulo k bytes if it is a multiple of k.1 Due to computer architecture, we are concerned only with alignments that are powers of 2, 2p. The maximum alignment of an address is the greatest power of 2 that it is a multiple of. For example, the powers of 2 that divide 120 (8•3•5) are 1, 2, 4, and 8, but not 16 or greater. So 8 is the maximum alignment of address 120.
Regarding extended alignment, the C standard defines a number of standard types including char, short, int, float, and pointers. Each of these types has an alignment requirement. The alignments of these standard types are called fundamental alignments. To satisfy the basic requirements of the C standard, a C implementation has to support these fundamental alignments. However, a C implementation may also support stricter alignments. These are called extended alignments. It just means an alignment to a greater power of 2 than is necessary for the basic objects.

… and can't the alignment of a pointer be found with the alignof operator?

No, because the alignof operator can only be applied to a type, not to an object. The C standard defines alignof (int) but not alignof x or alignof (x), where x is the name of an object.
Even if alignof were specified to apply to an object, similarly to sizeof, it would likely be specified only to give the alignment requirement of the type, not the actual maximum alignment of the object at hand, as other uses of sizeof and alignof are compile-time constants for types other than variable-length array types.
Footnote
1 Or, if the address space is not “flat”, then the address’ distance from a reference point is a multiple of k bytes.

Put simply, an object is aligned if it resides at an address whose value is a multiple of the object's size (or, if it's an array, struct, or union, a multiple of the largest subobject size).
So a 2 byte object is aligned if it's address is a multiple of 2, a 4 byte object is aligned if it's address is a multiple of 4, etc.
The memalignment function is basically stating that, given a particular address, what's the largest object that can be placed there and still be properly aligned.  Assuming a flat address space (i.e. an address is just a single number), this essentially returns the value of the lowest set bit in the address.
This lowest set bit is what is mean by "maximum alignment".  "Extended alignment" means a value larger than alignof(max_align_t), where max_align_t is an object whose alignment is the largest supported by a given implementation.
Using alignof isn't equivalent as it takes a type name, not a pointer value, and gives the alignment of that type.
